# rails datetime in separate fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I may have over-complicated what I need to do but this is what I now have.

I have a jobs controller that has 2 fields

```
starts_at as DATETIME
end_time as DATETIME
```

I save the event_date in a form using a

```
calendar_date_select :starts_at ,:time => false
```

I save the date time as

```
time_select :starts_at, {:twelve_hour => true}
```

This saves the Event date i.e 12/26/2009  and the start time as 7:00 pm

I need to also save the event end_time without having to re-enter the date, just the time

```
time_select :end_time, {:twelve_hour => true}
```

If i just use the above, the time is correct but the date dafaults to 01/01/2000

How do I save the date with the same date from starts_at?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, if the `:end_time` is nil, set it to the :starts_at variable like so:

```
object.end_time = object.starts_at unless not object.end_time.nil?
```

You may be able to shorten the end to

```
object.end_time = object.starts_at unless object.end_time.present?
```

but I'm not sure which version of Rails you are using and what the default implementation of `.present?` does for dates.

Comment: Where in my controller should this be.  I have placeed it above my update acction and nothing happens.   but also wouldnt this set just the date forgeting the time?

Comment: You would need to do this in both your new and edit controller methods if you want them to be editable by the user. If you don't want the user to have any control over it, then you could put it in the create and update methods at the top like you said you have done.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the model or controller, but isn't it possible that an event will start late at night and end on the following day? To allow for this possibility I'd recommend having two `calendar_date_select`s and auto-assigning the ending date when the starting date is chosen (so the second `calendar_date_select` will rarely be used).

If you really don't want two calendars, maybe use a hidden field for the ending date that follows the start date.

I wouldn't enforce this same-date rule below the interface level unless you're absolutely sure different start and end dates will never occur.